# org-indent-line always adds a comma before an leading asterisk in code block

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Launch Emacs with `emacs -q` and write in org-mode:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC C
/*
 * This is a comment line
 */
#+END_SRC
```

Press `TAB` inside the block. It becomes:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC C
/*
 ,* This is a comment line
 ,*/
#+END_SRC
```

Is there any way to get rid of this behevior?

Comment: This is a quoting mechanism to make sure that the asterisks are not interpreted as headline markers and throwing off Org mode's parser. See [Literal Examples](https://orgmode.org/manual/Literal-Examples.html) in the manual. No way to turn it off.

Comment: @NickD: That sounds like an answer...

Answer (score 1):

This is a quoting mechanism to make sure that the asterisks are not interpreted as headline markers and throwing off Org mode's parser. See [Literal Examples](https://orgmode.org/manual/Literal-Examples.html) in the manual.

There is no way to turn it off and you shouldn't anyway because Org mode will be very confused otherwise. The commas do not affect the exporting of the document or the evaluation of a source block: they are properly stripped at the appropriate time.

EDIT in response to a comment: You can edit the example block with `C-c '` (bound to `org-edit-special`): the comma is not included in the special edit buffer. When you finish the editing and type another `C-c '` in that buffer, the block gets updated in the Org mode buffer, adding the comma back to protect it from being misinterpreted. From my POV, making the comma invisible is a bad idea.